# Hangfire job not firing when called inside of ASP.NET MVC Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

The hangfire job does not start when putting it inside of an Index method in MVC. I can't figure out why.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => GetCurrentUserNotifications(User.Identity.Name), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));

      return View(vm);
}

public void GetCurrentUserNotifications(string userId)
{

    _connectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>()
        .Clients.All.broadcastNotifications(_repository.GetNotifications()
        .Where(x => x.DateTime <= DateTime.Now && x.CreatedBy == userId));
}
```

Comment: You can enable Hangfire dashboard, go to for example http://localhost:1234/hangfire. It should show what error it encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your method `GetCurrentUserNotifications(string userId)` is a method of your controller class. When Hangfire execute the job, it will try to create an instance of your controller class. But I believe your controller class does not have a parameter less constructor. So it will fail to execute the job.
The solution is to create a separate class, for example `BackgroundProcess`. Put your `GetCurrentUserNotifications` in to it, and call like below:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => new BackgroundProcess().GetCurrentUserNotifications(User.Identity.Name), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
```